# get image width and height within $.each

Tags: jquery, load

For the purpose of loading images in background I use $.each to iterate the **fNames** array which holds the images paths. For each of the loaded images I get 0 for width and height in the **load** method.
Code follows -

```
$.each(fNames, function (a, b) {
    var imm = new Image();
    $(imm).load(function () {
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).height();
        console.log(b + " --> " + w + " X " + h);
        $(this).appendTo("#imgList");
    })
    .click(function () {
        $(".dialogImage").css("border", "none");
        $(this).css("border", "2px solid black");
        selectedImage = b;
    })
    .addClass("dialogImage")
    .attr({
        "src": "/customers/" + $("#IDHiddenField1").val() + "/" + $("#projectIDHiddenField1").val() + "/" + b,
        "title": b
    });
});
```

How can I get width and height of the loaded images ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```